# Executing output of python from loop in bash

Tags: python, arrays, bash, eval, execution

I wrote a bash that has python command included in loop: (part of script)

```
#!/bin/bash

ARG=( $(echo "${@:3}"))
for (( i=1; i<=$#-3; i++ ))
do
python -c "print('<Command with variables>' * 1)"
done
```

When I run it, depends on number of my args for example I have this output:

```
nohup command-a &
nohup command-b &
nohup command-c &
```

How do I execute the output lines from bash immediately?

Can I tell python command to run them in each iteration? How?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking two questions. I can only answer the first one:

If you want to run commands coming to the standard output, just redirect them to bash:

```
python -c 'print "ls"' | bash
```

Comment: Ok, Your answer is good for my two questions...So I can do it:`do python -c "('nohup <command> &') * 1" | bash` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by executing the python code in a sub-shell and evaluating the content of that shell afterwards.

```
eval $(python -c ...)
```

`$()` returns a string you can evaluate with `eval`